# print one part of mongo document in pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I am using pymongo to query a json file.

I have queried the json file to find the most popular book and the counts of that book sold.

I am using pymongo and pipelines for my query. This is the format of my query

books = list(db.books.aggregate(pipeline1))

I have stored this result list in a variable called "books".

When I print books, i.e. print(books)

it prints the following:

{'_id': 'Harry Potter ', 'sold': 456289}

Is there anyway to print just the name: "Harry Potter" without "id", "sold" or "456289"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you inserted in your pipeline the projection step disabling the _id field?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

in details from documentation:

```
_id: <0 or false>
```

Specifies the suppression of the _id field.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. If I add :
##command3 = {"$project":{_ id <0 or false>} }  
##pipeline1.append(command3)
to my code this should work- thank you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.When I added :
##command3 = {"$project":"_ id" :0} }  
##pipeline1.append(command3)
to my code, it did work- thank you :)